# Getting QuerySnapshot instead of DocumentSnapshot [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

```
StreamBuilder(
         stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
         builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return CircularProgressIndicator();
           }
           FirestoreUser firestoreUser =
               FirestoreUser.fromDocument(snapshot.data); // Here snapshot.data is retrieving QuerySnapshot.
               // How I can convert it to DocumentSnapshot 
          ...
```

## Hello StackOverflow users

I need to give to my new firestoreUser variable, which type of DocumentSnapshot. But I can't get it.

After writing snapshot.data it gives me an error called "QuerySnapshot is not subtype of DocumentSnapshot"

**P.s I'm using StreamBuilder as you can see. Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stream is `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots()` which is a QuerySnapshot, meaning, a List of QueryDocumentSnapshot which Extends DocumentSnapshot.
So if you want the documentSnapshot of every users in your 'users' collection, you will have to iterate over snapshot.data.docs:
But if you want to get the document of a particular user, then you can do:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
         stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).snapshots(),
         builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return CircularProgressIndicator();
           }
           FirestoreUser firestoreUser =
               FirestoreUser.fromDocument(snapshot.data); 
          ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arnaud Delubac. Good luck man!